# Oracle Endeca Commerce:- Duplicate properties after joining

Tags: duplicates, left-join, records, endeca

I have two data sources 1) ATG_Data (Data Source 1)  and 2) Text Record. After joining both the sources the output is not coming as desired.

For Example,

There are two records (present in both sources). Both the records have these three properties but they definalty have other properties as well.

```
              Item Id   Vendor Id   Ranking(P_CommPtp)
```

Record 1           703595     2560              10
Record 2           703595     5638              11

But the Final Record after joining (left join) is

```
     Item Id    Vendor Id   Ranking(P_CommPtp)
```

Record 1    703595  2560    10
Record 2    703595  5638    11
Record 3    703595  2560    10  11
Record 4    703595  5638    10  11

Two more records are getting created, with the ranking merged.

In the pipeline, we are caching the data based on the following index.

ATG Data - 1) Item Number

```
               2) Vendor Id
```

Text File - 1) Item Number

We are using the left join.

I am not able to understand why 2 more records are getting created. we are doing indexing at sku level. and these three properties doesn't signify uniqueness of the records. 
Can u please help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

In the Record Assembler screen in the pipeline diagram (where you configure the join type, etc), I would experiment with the 2 check boxes "Multi-sub records" and "Remove Duplicate property values".   I think the first one might help with this.